# How to throw an array of marker in the props?

Tags: vue.js

Good afternoon, help, how to pass data through the props to display points

i used Map here

My code:

In compknents maps:

```
const marker = new H.map.Marker({lat: this.coords lng: this.coords]);
            map.addObject(marker);
```

Page where init components

```
<map-comp
      :coord = сюда точки
      :show-chart="selectedValueShow"/>
```

Getters:

```
test() {
      return this.$store.getters.locationsTracking
    }
```

A nested array comes in, in the getters. Help to do please

Comment: Is this `map-comp` is your own component or provided by third party plugin?

Comment: My own component

Answer (score 0):

Add your **own property** to your own map-comp component and use **computed property** of parent component. or you can use same getter to map-comp component it self.

```
<map-comp :show-chart="selectedValueShow" :[componentProperty]="markers"/>

// in parent component
    computed: {
       markers: function() { return this.$store.getters.locationsTracking; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide link, so I can help you more on this